# Api post, empty body object

Tags: node.js, postman

I'm trying to setup a basic API using `node` with 'body-parser', when I post my details:

```
localhost:3000/users?email=test.com&givenName=test
```

My `req.body.email` is empty, how can I post my details? I am using `body-parser` like this:

```
// create express app
const app = express();

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

My controller:

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    // Validate request
    if (!req.body.email) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "user cannot be empty"
        });
    }

    // Create a user
    const user = new user({
        email: req.body.email || "No Emails",
        givenName: req.body.givenName || "No Emails",
        familyName: req.body.familyName || "No Emails"
    });

    // Save user in the database
    user
        .save()
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                    err.message ||
                    "Some error occurred while creating the user."
            });
        });
};
```

Comment: use cors as well https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 0):

I tried code similar to yours and it's working fine, make sure you are hitting POST request from Postman. See code below,

```
'use strict';

// Initialize an Express application
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// parse application/json
app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json(res.body);
});

// Start the express application
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong, but do you mix [`body`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body) and [`query`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) up? Therefore there might be two reasons:

1.) Not mixing `body` and `query` up, but missing `body`:

Your request should look like the following statement:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{"email":"test.com","givenName":"test","familyName":"test"}' 'localhost:3000/users'
```

Afterwards you can access the values via `req.body.email`, `req.body.givenName` and `req.body.familyName`.

2.) Mixing `body` and `query` up:

Access your values via `req.query.email`, `req.query.givenName` and properly `req.query.familyName`.